# Do 4% of Americans say they believe in "lizard people"?

Tags: united-states, politics

Public Policy Polling reported in an [an opinion poll](http://www.publicpolicypolling.com/main/2013/04/conspiracy-theory-poll-results-.html)
that:

> 4% of voters say they believe “lizard people” control our societies by gaining political power

Lizard people are also known as reptilians.

Is that (and other results) from this poll reliable?

Comment: What evidence would take to convince you? Considering that *Public Policy Polling* is reputable and their poll can be considered as a reference.

Comment: There is actually a claim (made at least in my statistics classes in university 15 years ago) that there are about 5% of people in every survey that agree with any claim not matter how outlandish. If that's true 4% for lizard people is well within the expected margin.

Comment: @EikePierstorff: true, though you can eliminate that via having same question twice with different phrasing, where answering "yes" to both would be self contradictory and eliminated from results. I don't think they've done that here though.

Comment: @EikePierstorff 95% of people agree with you on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Results from this poll seem to be reliable. Public Policy Polling (PPP) who is a U.S. polling firm based in Raleigh, North Carolina released a [PDF report listing the results of a national survey looking at common conspiracy theories](http://www.publicpolicypolling.com/pdf/2011/PPP_Release_National_ConspiracyTheories_040213.pdf).

The exact question:

> Do you believe that **shape-shifting reptilian people control our world by taking on human form and gaining political power to manipulate our societies**, or not?

Answers:

> **Do:** 4%  
>   **Do not:** 88%  
>   **Not sure:** 7%

The wire.com [took](http://www.thewire.com/national/2013/04/12-million-americans-believe-lizard-people-run-our-country/63799/) the findings and arranged them from most-to least-believed:

> **Conspiracy**    *Percent believing* Number of Americans believing 
>   **JFK was killed by conspiracy**   *51 percent*    160,096,160  
>   **Bush intentionally misled on Iraq WMDs**  *44 percent*    138,122,178  
>   **Global warming is a hoax**    *37 percent*    116,148,195  
>   **Aliens exist**    *29 percent*    91,035,072  
>   **New World Order** *28 percent*    87,895,931  
>   **Hussein was involved in 9/11**    *28 percent*    87,895,931  
>   **A UFO crashed at Roswell**    *21 percent*    65,921,948  
>   **Vaccines are linked to autism**   *20 percent*    62,782,808  
>   **The government controls minds with TV**   *15 percent*    47,087,106  
>   **Medical industry invents diseases**   *15 percent*    47,087,106  
>   **CIA developed crack** *14 percent*    43,947,966  
>   **Bigfoot exists**  *14 percent*    43,947,966  
>   **Obama is the Antichrist** *13 percent*    40,808,825  
>   **The government allowed 9/11** *11 percent*    34,530,544  
>   **Fluoride is dangerous**   *9 percent* 28,252,264  
>   **The moon landing was faked**  *7 percent* 21,973,983  
>   **Bin Laden is alive**  *6 percent* 18,834,842  
>   **Airplane contrails are sinister chemicals**   *5 percent* 15,695,702  
>   **McCartney died in 1966**  *5 percent* 15,695,702  
>   **Lizard people control politics**  *4 percent* 12,556,562

The PDF report also mentioned that isurveyed 1,247 registered voters and has a margin of error of 2.8 percent:

> PPP surveyed **1,247 registered American voters** from March 27th to 30th. The margin of
>   error for the overall sample is **+/-2.8%**. This poll was not paid for or authorized by any
>   campaign or political organization. PPP surveys are conducted through automated
>   telephone interviews.

As for Public Policy Polling (PPP), it can be [considered as accurate](http://www.publicpolicypolling.com/track/hire-ppp-track.html) since a Fordham University [report](http://www.politico.com/blogs/media/2012/11/the-most-accurate-polls-of-148876.html) released ranked the firm first among 28 organizations for the accuracy of its final, national estimates. It also a [great track record and history in being accurate](http://www.publicpolicypolling.com/track/hire-ppp-track.html).

Comment: Hmm, I wonder, would **Bush intentionally misled on Iraq WMDs** actually be considered a conspiracy theory of the same caliber given the amount of information pointing to large scale deception that led up to that? The rest on the list don't have much in the way of reliable evidence, and they are generally viewed high on the "crackpot index".

Comment: Man, those reduced labels for the different conspiracies are strange. I mean, Aliens almost certainly exist somewhere and A UFO absolutely crashed at Roswell, it was probably a balloon, but it still was unidentified, flying and an object. It isn't expressly related but I'd like to see the actual questions for some of the more oddly worded items in the conspiracy list.

Comment: PPP has a great track record for *political* polls. Does that extend to conspiracy theory polls? How did PPP arrive at a 2.8% margin of error? Are they assuming that registered voters take lizard people as seriously as politics?

Comment: I'm actually surprised that only 5% believe McCartney died in 1966.

Comment: @DampeS8N, there is a link to the PDF report, it has all the questions there.

Comment: I'm a little worried now.  I am one of the 9 percent in the [fluoride is dangerous](http://www.mintpressnews.com/new-study-confirms-negative-impact-of-fluoride-on-thyroid-gland/202622/) camp.  Am I a loon?

Comment: And 70% believe there's a dude up in space who made everything with magic...

Comment: @Rainbolt - they only have a great track record if you're politically biased. There's nothing like being **called out by Nate Silver** to show you up as biased http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/heres-proof-some-pollsters-are-putting-a-thumb-on-the-scale/ :)

Comment: *"The government controls minds with TV"* — it's called propaganda :-P

Comment: @Lumberjack I suppose there's a line between believing that flouride is bad for health, and believing that the government puts flouride in public water and toothpaste *because* they know it's bad for health. The latter is definitely a conspiracy theory.

Comment: @JasonR Clearly, the "WMD lie" thing is also a conspiracy theory. Of course, it's a true one. But, once a conspiracy theory is true, does it stop being true? For example, most historians support the theory that Julius Caesar was assassinated as part of a conspiracy. It seems like a true CT. So, it's still a conspiracy theory. What I mean is: Some people only use the term CT to refer to something that's clearly false. If they're talking about Caesar's assassination or Iran Contra or the Lavon Affair, they may refer to it as "historical record" or something like that. (Continued...)

Comment: @JasonR The problem with this is that it renders the term “conspiracy term” completely useless. Because if it implies that something is just a crazy story, then why use the term? You could instead say “factually inaccurate story” or “speculative conspiratorial claims”, etc. History is full of various groups *conspiring* to do various nefarious things, so most historians have to entertain plenty of “conspiracy theories” as part of their work. Only using the term “conspiracy theory” when *we* believe something is wrong is highly subjective and, IMO, not useful to a scientific exchange of ideas.

Comment: @Fiksdal That was sort of my point in the observation I made. :)  Hence my use of "crackpot index" in my comment.

Comment: @JasonR Oh, ok, so you're saying 'conspiracy theory' as a term is not useful? (I agree with that, btw.)

Comment: sad to see only 7% believe in the moon landing hoax